# how to set limit area Manipulation

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have multiple TextBlock in a grid. I want to the user could move TextBlock by mouse.

I use manipulation for that but I couldn't limit area for the transition so sometimes control go to out of windows.

Comment: Add it to Microsoft UWP toolkit, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Floating Panel](https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2016/02/08/a-floating-panel-control-for-uwp/comment-page-1/) created by Diederik Krols

```
<controls:FloatingContent Boundary="Parent">
    <TextBlock />
</controls:FloatingContent>
```